# What is the correct APA citation style with two places and two publishers

Tags: citation-style

Is this the correct [APA form of citation](http://www.bibme.org/citation-guide/apa/) with two publishers in different locations?

Cazes, S., & Verick, S. (2013). The labour markets of emerging economies: Has growth translated into more and better jobs? Geneva. UK: ILO-Palgrave Macmillan.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

From this APA [library guide](http://irsc.libguides.com/apa/publisherreferencecitation) it says;

> If more than one publisher is given, use the first one or the one that
>   represents the home office, if given.

This answer at [writer stackexchange](https://writers.stackexchange.com/a/23826) supports this as well

So for your example the following should be fine for APA

> Cazes, S., & Verick, S. (2013). *The labour markets of emerging
>   economies: Has growth translated into more and better jobs?* Geneva:
>   ILO.

Comment: The title should be in italics though, no?

Comment: @OGC Yes it should, my bad. Edited now.

Answer (score 12):

I'm going to say something perhaps controversial here: I do not believe that location information is really relevant any more.

Consider, in your example, Palgrave Macmillan: Wikipedia tells me [it is located in London, New York, Shanghai, Melbourne, Sydney, Hong Kong, Delhi, and Johannesburg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palgrave_Macmillan).  And what good does it do to know that?  After all, anyone attempting to access the reference is going to use a library or the internet, rather than attempting to physically call some office in Melbourne to order a copy.  My point is that I think you should fill in this obsolete slot with something reasonable (like you have done), but that I don't think it will actually matter to anybody.

It does seem reasonable to keep both imprints of publisher, and a hyphen like you've used (or maybe a slash) seem like reasonable enough ways of doing so.

Comment: I feel your sentiment and don't find it controversial, but it's not how APA says you should do it.